# How to make SQL Memory Optimized Native Compiled Function Deterministic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is a really, really simple function, it comes back deterministic.  If I compile it native it's no longer deterministic.  How can I make it native compiled and deterministic?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [hash].[HashDelimiter2]()
RETURNS NCHAR(1)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN
        RETURN N';'
END
GO

/* This does indeed result in YES */
SELECT IS_DETERMINISTIC
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'HashDelimiter2'



/* But then compile it native and it's no longer deterministic */
CREATE FUNCTION [hash].[HashDelimiter3]()
RETURNS NCHAR(1)
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH (
    TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT,
    LANGUAGE = N'English'
)
    RETURN N';'
END
GO

/* This results in NO */
SELECT IS_DETERMINISTIC
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'HashDelimiter3'
```

Comment: Have you found ANY sprocs that are native that return as deterministic?

Comment: I have not found any deterministic native functions, all of them that I write come out non-deterministic.

Comment: just a guess, as the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) is not giving away this detail: have you ruled out the `ATOMIC WITH` part as the cause already? setting the transaction isolation level is likely to affect global state and qualify for non-determinism. btw. which version are you using?

Comment: 2016 RTM, and the atomic with is required with NATIVE_COMPILATION

Answer (score 1):

only a guess, I do not have 2016 to test it,
but I will try to change:

```
RETURN N';'
```

TO

```
DECLARE @R AS NCHAR(1) = N';'
RETURN @R
```

I think the problem is that `N';'` is created as `NVARCHAR(1)` and then implicit converted to `NCHAR(1)` so maybe the conversion make it non deterministic.

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @AaronStainback did you give it a try? I'm curious :)

Comment: Nope still comes back 'NO' :(